# Inquiring about Programming Practices on SO

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions

I've never posted a question to SO, before, and my Python question relates to idioms as well as best practices. I thought it best that I initially present my question here, as asking permission to ask seems to be one possible use of Meta. The question could provoke endless discussion, or it could lead to an answer which otherwise eludes me, hence my quandary.

Is this post suitable as a question for Stack Overflow?

Question follows:

> I maintain a single Python project which my customers execute on a number of interpreter versions, 2.4.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.6, 2.7.8, and unknown versions which follow the previously named. Because my deliverable is a single file, my code must evaluate the version of the interpreter and make decisions accordingly. I intend to constrain most of these differences to functions with checks against `sys.version_info`, but seek community guidance for Pythonic best practices which apply to this situation. I wish to know how others have handled this situation, and what seasoned Python programmers consider legible when they are hired to manage projects built with such constraints.
>
> This project prevents control of interpreter versions, as I am not in a position to dictate requirements for the host systems.

Comment: Rather than using phrases like "I seek community guidance" and asking how others have handled it, just explain what you want to do and ask how to do it. That is far less subjective and will get you much better answers (and less resistance from the community).

Comment: Are you prepared for the canonical response _"Don't do version detection, do feature detection "_?

Comment: ["best practices"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/1228)

Comment: @CodeCaster it's not obvious to me that response makes sense in the context of Python, which has a finite number of releases whose release notes are all available online. I'm familiar with the advice to use feature detection instead of user agent detection or environment detection in JavaScript, but that's because there are zillions of JavaScript engines out there and you can't possibly cover them all. In Python, where that concern doesn't apply, I might well favour simple (commented) version detection over using (potentially complicated) tricks to detect features, at *least* in some cases.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

First off, this is totally appropriate for a Meta question. More people should consider asking "Is this cool" on Meta if they aren't sure. So bravo to that.

To the main question, I don't believe Stack Overflow is the *best* site for this question. Would it be appropriate at all? Perhaps. I don't think it would get closed as off-topic outright. But the best site for this (in my opinion) would be [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Stack Overflow is generally more concerned with the code itself. Algorithms, data structures, that kind of thing. Programmers tends to cater to things like best practices, SDLC, even things like design patterns (although admittedly, that one is a bit fuzzier.)

What makes it tricky is that you've mentioned that your code would be different for whatever version the target is. And adding the actual code into the mix does make it lean back toward SO.

At the end of the day, I think Programmers is your best bet, but if you were to ask it on SO I would expect it to get answered, probably with at least one good answer, and also probably by an expert. I would not expect it to get closed, unless it was to be migrated.

That said, I'm not a Python guy, and I'm not as active on Programmers as perhaps I should be, so if someone more of an expert in either came along and contradicted me, I would defer to their judgement. (Except the first part. As a diamond mod elsewhere, I assure you that asking on Meta if you can ask a question on that Meta's main is absolutely the right call. Also, all the mods have a **cough** super secret line of communication **cough** and so if a question like this comes up we can quickly ask around to reach a consensus.)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that programmers.stackexchange.com existed, and I'll look into posting this over there. I appreciate your time and consideration.

Comment: @GarrettEllis if you decide to post at Programmers, consider giving a read to [Making “best practices” questions more palatable: how to ask a “best practice” question that is acceptable to the community?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7091/31260)